# Can someone please help me understand the structure of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

ようやくきたかって感じでした

I'm assuming ようやく is 踊躍 and きた is from 来る but I'm not really sure what the meaning of the sentence is.

Comment: Heres another way to write it: 漸く来たかという感じでした

Comment: "I was like, 'About time!'"

Answer (score 5):

- ようやく: not 踊躍 but [漸く](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%BC%B8%E3%81%8F), meaning "at last", "finally". It's usually written in hiragana since it's an adverb.
- 来た: "came"
- か: a surprise marker rather than a question marker in this case. (eg そうか! = "Oh, I got it!", お前か! = "Oh, it's you!")
- ～って感じでした = ～という感じでした: "It was like ～", "I kinda thought/felt ～". ～という感じ is often used to make the sentence milder and less affirmative.

The whole sentence roughly means "I kinda thought 'Finally you came!' "

Comment: Thank you. So って in this is short for という?

Comment: @debrucey Yes, it is.